# How to achieve better quality in creating video from .jpg files with avconv?

Tags: video, hd-video, video-conversion

I'm trying to make video from many jpg files exported by paraView. I have already found out that 'avconv' can do that but the output quality is just not so good even with -s hd1080 option written in.

Jpeg files resolution is 1920x1080 so I believe they could do some good for me.

File size isn't that much important, I want to be able to see details on the video.

Is it even possible?

If it is important I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried cranking up the bitrate with the -b option? That should normally take care of any quality issues. Completely lossless conversion from JPEG to MJPEG should also be possible in theory, but not sure if any Linux software supports that.

Comment: Very thanks. With your comment i have done `avconv -i %04d.jpg -r 25 -b 65536k video.avi` and now it looks exactly as I wanted - sharp and clear. Thank you @Grumbel !

Comment: Do you have to use avconv?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned.